# Increment minute to the nearest 15 minute interval

Tags: php, date, datetime, intervals

I think I am almost there - trying to get the current time then add an hour to it then output the options to 15 mins intervals - so if it is 14:12 the first available slot would be 14:15 and then every 15 mins till my end time

```
$start  = new DateTime("Now");
$start->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

$end          = new DateTime("2015-05-16 17:00");
$interval     = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period       = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$current_date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A');
$current_time = strtotime($current_date);


foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    echo $dt->format('H:i')."<br>";
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how do I round up to 15 mins intervals so 14:15, 14:30, 14:45, 15:00

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$min15InSecs = 15*60;
$min15 = time()-(time()%$min15InSecs)+$min15InSecs;

$start  = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i", $min15));
$start->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));

$end  = new DateTime("2015-05-16 19:00");
$interval = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$current_date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A');
$current_time = strtotime($current_date);


foreach ($period as $dt)
{

    echo $dt->format('H:i')."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clamp a number to the next multiple of 15 like this:

```
ceil($num / 15) * 15
```

Adjust the `$start` date as described above. Example:

```
$start   = new DateTime("today 14:12"); // 2015-05-16 14:12:00
$hour    = (int) $start->format("H");   // 14
$minute  = (int) $start->format("i");   // 12
$clamped = ceil($minute / 15) * 15;     // 15
$start->setTime($hour, $clamped);       // 2015-05-16 14:15:00
```

[`setTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) note: values exceeding ranges are added to their parent values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your problem is how to get to the right 15th minute?

Does that solve your problem?:

```
<?php

$start          = new DateTime("Now");
$currentMinutes = $start->format('i');

if ($currentMinutes > 15) {
    $start->setTime(($start->format('H') + 1), 15);
} elseif($currentMinutes < 15) {
    $start->setTime($start->format('H'), 15);
}

$end          = new DateTime("2015-05-16 17:00");
$interval     = new DateInterval('PT15M');
$period       = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$current_date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A');
$current_time = strtotime($current_date);


foreach ($period as $dt)
{
    echo $dt->format('H:i')."<br>";
}
```

Or in case you like it short:

```
$start          = new DateTime("2015-05-16 13:15");
$currentMinutes = $start->format('i');
$currentHour    = $start->format('H');
$start->setTime(($currentMinutes > 15 ? ++$currentHour : $currentHour), 15);
[...]
```